# Youtube Iframe Api not working on live website

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using youtube iframe API for redirecting users to another link when the video ends. I've an existing iframe on my webpage. So I've written the below code which works on my local environment but in the live website it doesn't work.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
window.YT.ready(function () {
    player = new window.YT.Player(element_id, {
                        events: {
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                });
            };

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    if (quiz_permalink) {
                        window.location.href = quiz_permalink;
                    } else if (next_lesson_permalink) {
                        window.location.href = next_lesson_permalink;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone guide me what can be the possible reason for this not working in the live website ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Describe *not working*

Comment: `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function isn't getting called and so does the `onStateChange` event.

Comment: Can you try debugging into what's not working? You may open the browser developer tools console and try tracing down the execution using `console.log`. Hope it heps.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya as I said it's working fine in local and I used the same debugging technique to get it done there but somehow it's not working in LIVE website

Comment: It's not still clear what's "not working" from your info. It would help if you could tell us what error you get and how you've tried debugging it.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function isn't getting called and neither does it give any error in console. I traced the execution using `console.log`.

Thanks